# Highcharts-ng directive (Angular) not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-scope, highcharts-ng

I'm using [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) Angular-JS directive to draw a chart on my page.

I am hoping to be able to update the data in my controller, and have these values reflected in the graph. However, when I update a $scope variable using assignment eg:

```
$scope.chartData = [1, 2, 3];
```

...then the graph is not updated. The only way I can get the graph updated is to push a value into the data, eg:

```
$scope.chartData.push(4);
```

...however this works only the first time it is performed. Here's a JS-fiddle showing what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/K6hL8/

I'm new to Angular so I wanted to check whether there is an obvious problem with my Angular code (maybe I misunderstand $scope and two way bindings?) before I start blaming the third party directive.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

So it appears (in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6hL8/) that Angular *does* see the change in chartData (I've put a watch with an alert on it), but only when watch is called with "true" for equality. All the watches in the directive use 'true', so I'm stumped...

Comment: Author of the directive here. There was a bug that has now been fixed. Your jsfiddle now works!

Comment: Hi - thanks for letting me know - and for the directive too!

Answer (score 8):

You are modifying a temporary data variable which is used to apply to actual chart. 
You need to modify directly `.series` data

```
    var data  = $scope.chartConfig.series[0].data;
    $scope.chartConfig.series[0].data = data.concat([data.length]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K6hL8/4/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I can edit $scope.chartConfig, and Angular watches this - that's great - but shouldn't I be able to edit $scope.chartData too and have the parent object update? 

It works the first time I push a new value into it, just not subsequently.

Comment: ya, variables are referencing to same object, but may be that api cache data to another variable somewhere?